# Java regex replace a word that comes after another

Tags: java, regex

I have a string: "Foo value 1.1.1".

I want to replace the `1.1.1` with something else, say `***`?

I tried `str.replaceAll("[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]", "***")` and it works, but the word `1.1.1` can change and be "1.1" or "1.1.a" or "111", etc.

This word is always followed by the word "value" though. Thus I basically want to replace the word that comes after `value`, how can I do it using `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex like `(value\s)([\w\.?]+)` to match and group it,then use `$1` and `$2` to replace it.

In your case,`$1` represent for `vaule\s` and `$2` represent `[\w\.]+`,we just need to reserve `$1` and replace `$2`

```
    String str1 = "Foo value 1.1.1".replaceAll("(value\\s)([\\w\\.?]+)", "$1AAA");
    String str2 = "Foo value 1.1".replaceAll("(value\\s)([\\w\\.?]+)", "$1BBB");
    String str3 = "Foo value Stackoverflow".replaceAll("(value\\s)([\\w\\.?]+)", "$1CCC");
    System.out.println(str1);//output: Foo value AAA
    System.out.println(str2);//output: Foo value BBB
    System.out.println(str3);//output: Foo value CCC
```

---

Update,an more elegant way is to change regex to `(?<=value\s)[\w\.?]+`,output will be the same

```
String str1 = "Foo value 1.1.1".replaceAll("(?<=value\\s)[\\w\\.?]+", "AAA");
String str2 = "Foo value 1.1".replaceAll("(?<=value\\s)[\\w\\.?]+", "BBB");
String str3 = "Foo value Stackoverflow".replaceAll("(?<=value\\s)[\\w\\.?]+", "CCC");
System.out.println(str1);//output: Foo value AAA
System.out.println(str2);//output: Foo value BBB
System.out.println(str3);//output: Foo value CCC
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, just to try something new :-p - you could try using a "positive lookbehind":

```
groovy:000> a = "hello there Moi"
groovy:000> p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(?<=there\\s)\\w+")
groovy:000> m = p.matcher(a)
groovy:000> m.replaceAll("John")
===> hello there John
```

The regular expression `(?<=there\\s)\\w+` will match any word, if it is preceded by "there " (with any whitespace character, not just space, after "there")